# How do you find inflection points

Tags: calculus

$$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, f(x)=x^2e^{-x^2}$$

The second derivative is $f''(x)=e^{-x^2}(4x^4-10x^2+2)$.

So I need the solutions for $f''(x)=0$.
I tried to notate $x^2=t$ but i don't know if it's ok..

Any ideas? Please..

Comment: Of course $x^2 = t$ is okay. You just have to make sure that $t>0$ ...

Comment: And for $e^{-x^2}=0$? ( i know maybe is a stupid question ..) I need to make a table with the derivative and the critical points

Comment: A power of $e$ is always $>0$.

Answer (score 2):

$f''(x) = 0$ iff $(4x^4 - 10x^2 +2) = 0$ (as $e^{-x^2}>0$ always).

To solve the quartic we can indeed set $t=x^2$ and we need to solve

$(4t^2 - 10t + 2) =0$ and we only need to consider $t\ge 0$.

The discriminant is $100 - 4\times 4 \times 2= 68 >  0$, so solutions exist.. Find $t\ge 0$ and thus $x$..

Comment: Done! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mary You're welcome.